# Can't drop composite unique index in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I have a Lumen 5.5 (MySQL 5.7) app where I create a unique index in a database migration:

```
Schema::table('form_data', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->unique(['organisation_id', 'template_id', 'entity_type_id', 'entity_id'], 'form_data_identifier');
    // name of the index is 'form_data_identifier'
});
```

In the `down` migration, I try to drop the index:

```
Schema::table('form_data', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->dropUnique('form_data_identifier');
});
```

But I get the error message:

> In Connection.php line 664:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'form_data_identifier': needed in a foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `form_data` drop index `form_data_identifier`)

I've tried to run the query directly on the database myself using both `DROP INDEX x ON y` and `ALTER TABLE y DROP INDEX x` syntaxes, and I get the same error. I've checked, and this index `form_data_identifier` isn't referenced by any other table or key. (Note: some of the keys comprising the unique key **are** foreign keys, but I don't think that should be a problem.)

What could I be missing?

Comment: "Note: some of the keys comprising the unique key are foreign keys, but I don't think that should be a problem" - It **is** a problem as the error message says.

Comment: How? In case I wasn't clear, I meant that `organisation_id` and `template_id`reference `id` on `organisations`and `templates` tables respectively. Should that prevent me from dropping a different index? Wouldn't that be the other way round (i.e. if I was trying to drop those columns first)?

Comment: A *foreign key (constraint)* and an *index* are two different things. A *foreign key* always needs an index (on both tables) which can support the constraint check.

Comment: Do you have a table that marks one of these fields as a foreign key?  That would stop a deletion of the field.

Comment: @Forbs No, I don't

Comment: See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102371/mysql-how-to-check-foreign-keys-related-to-a-table) to find out how to find the table with the foreign key.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Just tried that. Empty result set.

Comment: If a table column *is* a foreign key, it needs an index on it as well. Creating the FK will add this index automatically, but you can't remove it.